# How to stop a variable from being referenced without removing it?

Tags: python, variables, speech-recognition

So as I am programming I created a variable (rYouTube) in which I store the Recognizer. I create another variable called rGoogle in which I store another Recognizer. The only problem is that I keep getting the error message "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rYouTube' referenced before assignment" everytime I choose Google instead of YouTube, because the way my program works is you choose one and the program continues (if you chose YouTube, you can look watch stuff, if you chose Google, you can look up stuff)

So I have already tried giving the variables values as placeholders but since these variables are audio variables it doesnt work.

```
                print("Would you like to Direct Search?")
            rYouTube = sr.Recognizer()
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                        rYouTube.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                        YTaudio = rYouTube.listen(source)
                        print("LOADING...")
                        time.sleep(1)

        try:
                DirectYTRecognized = rYouTube.recognize_google(YTaudio)
                print(DirectYTRecognized)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
                print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


        if "yes" in DirectYTRecognized:
                print("What do you want to watch?")
        SearchYouTube = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
                        SearchYouTube.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                        YTSearchAudio = SearchYouTube.listen(source)
                        print("LOADING...")
                        time.sleep(1)

        try:
                FinalSearchYTAudio = SearchYouTube.recognize_google(YTSearchAudio)
                print(FinalSearchYTAudio)
            DirectYT = "https://youtube.com/results?search_query=" + FinalSearchYTAudio
            webbrowser.open_new(DirectYT)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
                print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

#END OF YT DIRECT SEARCH-------------------------------------

#GOOGLE DIRECT SEARCH---------------------------------------
        if "Google" in recognized:
                print("Would you like to Direct Search?")
            rGoogle = sr.Recognizer()
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                        rGoogle.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                        GoogleAudio = rGoogle.listen(source)
                        print("LOADING...")
                        time.sleep(1)

        try:
                DirectGoogleRecognized = rGoogle.recognize_google(GoogleAudio)
                print(DirectGoogleRecognized)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
                print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


        if "yes" in DirectGoogleRecognized:
                print("What do you want to look up?")
        SearchGoogle = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
                        SearchGoogle.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                        GoogleSearchAudio = SearchGoogle.listen(source)
                        print("LOADING...")
                        time.sleep(1)

        try:
                FinalSearchGooleAudio = SearchGoogle.recognize_google(YTSearchAudio)
                print(FinalSearchGoogleAudio)
            DirectGoogle = "https://youtube.com/results?search_query=" + FinalSearchGoogleAudio
            webbrowser.open_new(DirectGoogle)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
                print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

I expected the program to continue working but instead it stops and says: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rYouTube' referenced before assignment"

Answer (score 1):

Your Try Except statements should not be outdented as far as they are,  they should be indented to the same level as the with that precedes them.  (that is what appears to be the issue from the code you have posted with the formatting it is showing.

Comment: The reason why they are so far outdented is cause they are part of a funtion, I didn't include that in the code, sorry

Comment: in your code the variable that is coming back unbound is being assigned by a block that nested.   The try block is not in the same scope (its in an outer scope where the variable has not been set to anything yet.   indentation is important as far as variable scope.